# Appcelerator Studio - Don't stretch Image

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a 405x720 image that it is to cover the background image. I've noticed that it stretches the image if the device's screen is smaller than the image. (I'm using a Galaxy S4 to test my apps).

Here's what I have so far:

```
    var fullView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        layout: 'vertical',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        image: '/images/background.png'
    });
```

I've heard about the clipping technique, however that is only available for iOS and I'd like to have it for both platforms. Is there a way to do this? Or should I try to resize it appropriately? Tips/Suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use proper images according to the aspect ratio of screen you are going to run your app on.

You can do this by calculating the width-height ratio of device and then you can decide which image to show on.

But putting a single resolution image directly to cover up the whole screen 
is never going to work.

To resize an image, you can use **[Ti.Blob](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob)** class' methods after fetching your image using **[Ti.Filesystem](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem)**

Also remember that putting an image on whole background takes lot of memory especially in Android. That's why most of the apps do not use complete image to cover up background, rather they use small images wherever necessary and fills up other areas by colors or gradients as required.

But if your requirement is only to use image in background then unload it as soon as you move to different screen and load it again as you are back on it.

Further points to keep note of:

1. If you set bg image on a View, then it will be fit to cover the dimension of a View. So, if you have a view of width/height to 100%, then image will be fit into it. It means that image size will depend on View's dimension, not the View dimension will depend on image size.
2. If you set image on ImageView, and suppose you have:

   - ImageView width = FILL to screen size of 720, then the image height will be automatically decided to keep the aspect ratio. It means that if you have an image of size width=720 and height=400, then the ImageView will be of **width=FILL** & **height=400**
   - Image of size **width=1000** and **height=800** & ImageView height = 400, then the ImageView will be of **width=500** & **height=400**

Comment: How much does memory improve if I were to avoid using images as backgrounds, and then split them up and use specific images whenever needed? I have about 20 views that uses an image background.

Comment: To use an image for whole screen background, it can affect your app memory too much. Once I had only 5-6 screens which had image as bg, not sure now about the size of each bg image, but it was taking around 50MB in Android, after removing those images it took only 30MB around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're actually telling the image control to load the image on an object that is stretched to the entire width and height of the screen - and when the screen aspect ratio is different than the one you have cropped your image by then you get bad aspect ratio and image looks screwed up.

If you remove either the width or the height, than the aspect ratio of the image will be loaded.

When I want a background image what I found the best way is to make a square image, and then set my ImageView height to `Ti.UI.FILL` and my width to `Ti.UI.SIZE` - That way it shows good aspect ratio and side that dont "fit" the screen (width or height) are not shown.

Comment: When I tried to remove the width and height, it still gave me back a stretched out image. I think the only way to combat this is to either resize it so that it fits with my device, or to do what the guy above said, which was to not make background images but separate them into smaller bits. Either way, thank you for this information regarding on the Ti.UI.FILL and Ti.UI.SIZE, I might need this at some point later on.

Comment: Please see my edited answer as I have added some points to take care of.